# storing 4 different names and pointers for future use

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers

i have this function class called Pagemanager which goes like this

```
class Page : public Ipage //Ipage is abstract with pure virtual function
{
public: 
      page(void);
      ~page(void);
      virtual int FillDbgPage(char* sz, unsigned int max_bytes, 
      char* arg1, char*    arg2,  char* arg3, char* arg4){return 0;}
 };

//Pagemanager.h
class pageManager : public IPage
{
public:
      pageManager(void);
      ~pageManager(void);

      //client calls this function to register himself as a page content owners
      void registerPage(char* PageName, Page* PagePtr)

      //webserver calls this function to request page update
      int FillDbgPage(char* sz, unsigned int max_bytes, 
      char* arg1, char* arg2,  char* arg3, char* arg4);

Private:
       char name[10];    //stores the name of the page 
       Ipage* storePagePtr; //stores the address of the page
};

//pageManager.cpp
int pageManager::FillDbgPage(char* sz, unsigned int max_bytes, char* arg1, 
char*  arg2,  char* arg3, char* arg4)
{
if(arg4!=NULL)
{
  if (strcmp(arg4, name)==0)
  {
   cout<<"Page"<<arg4<<"Found"<<endl;

     if(storePagePtr==Null)
      cout<<"storePagePtr not initialized"<<endl;
     else
       int len = storePagePtr->FillDbgPage(sz, max_bytes, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
   else
     cout<<"Sorry"<<arg4<<not found!<<endl;
else
{
 strcat(sz, ("<a href = http://127.0.0.1/dbg_image_pipe?arg4="));
 strcat(sz, name);
 strcat(sz,">");
 strcat(sz, name);
 strcat)sz, "<br>");
 strcat(sz, ("</a>\n"));
}
return strlen(sz);
}
void pageManager::RegisterPage(char* PageName, Page *PagePtr)
{
 storePagePtr= PagePtr;
 strcpy(name, PageName);
}


//this is code from cpp file which will be done by end users for example
pageManager systemRegister;
class myPage1 : public Page
{
public:
       virtual int FillDbgPage(char* sz, unsigned int max_bytes, char* arg1, 
       char* arg2,  char* arg3, char* arg4)
{
      //sample content that user will print in the page he created
      sprintf(sz, "Hello World"! <br> This is my page!);
      return strlen(sz);
}

myPage1 Page1;

void module1_initialize()
{
systemRegister.RegisterPage("Page1", &Page1);
}
```

the problem is right now 1 page is created and it stores in name and sotrePagePtr
but what do i do if there are 4 pages. Lets say user wants 4 different files, how do i save them properly so that displaying them in future becomes easier

Comment: collection of `Page*`? or `Page` itself..

Comment: collection of name of page name, "Page1" and page*

Comment: sorry that was typo, should have been strcat(sz, "<br>");

Comment: @cybercop sounds like you want `std::map<std::string, Page*>`

Answer (score 0):

Use e.g. `std::vector<Page*>` and in `RegisterPage` use `push_back` method.
If you want to add a name to each page, you should handle the page and its name in a struct or class and use `std::vector` with this struct or class

Comment: so i replace my previous code char name[20] with vector<char> name[20] and IPage* storePageptr with vector<IPage>* storePageptr and in pageManager cpp file in RegisterPage method i do name.push_back(PageName) and storePagePtr.push_back(pageptr)?

Comment: Not really... Create a struct which contains the `name` and the `storePagePtr`. I would suggest to use `std::string` instead of `char` array. E.g. `struct PageManagerData { std::string * name; IPage * storePagePtr; }` and then `std::vector<PageManagerData*> pages`

Comment: thank you but i've slight problem. I have included string '#include string>' and have created a struct like 'struct PagemanagerData{string* name; IPage* storePageptr;};' then i have 'vector<pageManagerData*> pages;' but in cpp file how do i store pointers from function into those name and storePagePtr? I always keep getting error. I have 'Void pageManager::RegisterPage(char* PageName, Page* PagePtr){}' now inside this function i have to save these parameters into the name and storePagePtr. Sorry I just started with c++ :(

Comment: You have to create an instance of `PagemanagerData`, in `RegisterPage` do this: `PagemanagerData * tmp = new PagemanagerData(Pagename, Pageptr);` (you have to write this constructor for the struct) and then `pages.push_back(tmp);`. (As you can see we have used `new`, so you have to do the memory management, this means you will have to write a constructor too ([rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))), you can try to improve your solution with smart pointers later)